# Different baseline skip for first item after change in font size

Tags: beamer, xetex

I am having trouble getting the same baselike skip for each item in the following code.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{XYZ}
    \begin{itemize}
      {\fontsize{18pt}{30}\selectfont
      \item n is the number of states; 
      \item i is the start state.
      \item j is one of the final states.
      }
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: the size change should be before the itemize

Answer (score 1):

Don't enclose the font change in braces (`itemize` will provide them anyway):

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{XYZ}
    \begin{itemize}
      \fontsize{18pt}{30}\selectfont
      \item n is the number of states;
      \item i is the start state.
      \item j is one of the final states.
      \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]